# how can I keep the first entry by ID? pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, diff

pk_cid means client id
Each pk_partition represents the current state of the month of em_acount(which is a product sold). So if a client has 1 in january and also has 1 in February that means that he had only buy once in January. I would like to change the rest of the months to have a 0 if the previous month has a 1 to see exacly the time where people buy only keeping the first one.

if its possible on the other hand if a person left to have a -1

[This is what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbiBi.png)

you can create a pandas.Series:

```
a = pd.Series({(15891, '2018-07-28'): 1,
 (15891, '2018-08-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2018-11-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2018-12-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-01-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-02-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-03-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-04-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-05-28'): 0,
 (16203, '2018-12-28'): 0,
 (16203, '2019-01-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-02-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-03-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-04-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-05-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-09-28'): 0,
 (16502, '2018-10-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-11-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-12-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2019-01-28'): 1})
```

**Desired output**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g6kO.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please do not use images of your data. We cannot re-create your frame (or rather series in this case). Use `df.head(10).to_dict()` and paste the results into you questions.

Comment: here there is {(15891, '2018-07-28'): 1,
 (15891, '2018-08-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2018-11-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2018-12-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-01-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-02-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-03-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-04-28'): 0,
 (16063, '2019-05-28'): 0,
 (16203, '2018-12-28'): 0,
 (16203, '2019-01-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-02-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-03-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-04-28'): 1,
 (16203, '2019-05-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-09-28'): 0,
 (16502, '2018-10-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-11-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2018-12-28'): 1,
 (16502, '2019-01-28'): 1}

Answer (score 1):

I think this logic is correct, but it does assume that your dates are ordered in your index.

```
s = pd.Series( {(15891, '2018-07-28'): 1, (15891, '2018-08-28'): 0,
                (16063, '2018-11-28'): 0, (16063, '2018-12-28'): 0,
                (16063, '2019-01-28'): 0, (16063, '2019-02-28'): 0, 
                (16063, '2019-03-28'): 0, (16063, '2019-04-28'): 0, 
                (16063, '2019-05-28'): 0, (16203, '2018-12-28'): 0, 
                (16203, '2019-01-28'): 1, (16203, '2019-02-28'): 1, 
                (16203, '2019-03-28'): 1, (16203, '2019-04-28'): 1, 
                (16203, '2019-05-28'): 1, (16502, '2018-09-28'): 0, 
                (16502, '2018-10-28'): 1, (16502, '2018-11-28'): 1, 
                (16502, '2018-12-28'): 1, (16502, '2019-01-28'): 1})
# groupby level 0
g = s.groupby(level=0)
# create a mask based on your logic
mask = ((g.shift(0)==1) & (g.shift(-1)==1) & (g.shift()==1)) | \
       ((g.shift(0)==1) & (g.shift(-1).isna()) & (g.shift()==1)) | \
       ((g.shift(0)==1) & (g.shift(-1)==0) & (g.shift()==1))
# assign all true values to 0
s[mask] = 0
print(s)

15891  2018-07-28    1
       2018-08-28    0
16063  2018-11-28    0
       2018-12-28    0
       2019-01-28    0
       2019-02-28    0
       2019-03-28    0
       2019-04-28    0
       2019-05-28    0
16203  2018-12-28    0
       2019-01-28    1
       2019-02-28    0
       2019-03-28    0
       2019-04-28    0
       2019-05-28    0
16502  2018-09-28    0
       2018-10-28    1
       2018-11-28    0
       2018-12-28    0
       2019-01-28    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the index, then [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) `user_id` get [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.pct_change.html) and set the values to 0 if the change is `<= 0`:

```
serie = pd.Series( {(15891, '2018-07-28'): 1, (15891, '2018-08-28'): 0,
                    (16063, '2018-11-28'): 0, (16063, '2018-12-28'): 0,
                    (16063, '2019-01-28'): 0, (16063, '2019-02-28'): 0, 
                    (16063, '2019-03-28'): 0, (16063, '2019-04-28'): 0, 
                    (16063, '2019-05-28'): 0, (16203, '2018-12-28'): 0, 
                    (16203, '2019-01-28'): 1, (16203, '2019-02-28'): 1, 
                    (16203, '2019-03-28'): 1, (16203, '2019-04-28'): 1, 
                    (16203, '2019-05-28'): 1, (16502, '2018-09-28'): 0, 
                    (16502, '2018-10-28'): 1, (16502, '2018-11-28'): 1, 
                    (16502, '2018-12-28'): 1, (16502, '2019-01-28'): 1})

serie.sort_index(inplace=True)
serie [serie.groupby(level=0).pct_change() <= 0 ] = 0
serie

# 15891 2018-07-28 1
#       2018-08-28 0
# 16063 2018-11-28 0
#       2018-12-28 0
#       2019-01-28 0
#       2019-02-28 0
#       2019-03-28 0
#       2019-04-28 0
#       2019-05-28 0
# 16203 2018-12-28 0
#       2019-01-28 1
#       2019-02-28 0
#       2019-03-28 0
#       2019-04-28 0
#       2019-05-28 0
# 16502 2018-09-28 0
#       2018-10-28 1
#       2018-11-28 0
#       2018-12-28 0
#       2019-01-28 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    if dd.query("col3==1").pipe(len)>1:
        dd.loc[dd.query("col3==1").index[1]:,'col3']=0
    return dd
df1=a.reset_index()
df1.columns=['col1','col2','col3']
df1.groupby(['col1',df1.col3.eq(0).cumsum()|df1.col3.diff().gt(0).cumsum()],as_index=0,group_keys=0).apply(function1)

     col1        col2  col3
0   15891  2018-07-28     1
1   15891  2018-08-28     0
2   16063  2018-11-28     0
3   16063  2018-12-28     0
4   16063  2019-01-28     0
5   16063  2019-02-28     0
6   16063  2019-03-28     0
7   16063  2019-04-28     0
8   16063  2019-05-28     0
9   16203  2018-12-28     0
10  16203  2019-01-28     1
11  16203  2019-02-28     0
12  16203  2019-03-28     0
13  16203  2019-04-28     0
14  16203  2019-05-28     0
15  16502  2018-09-28     0
16  16502  2018-10-28     1
17  16502  2018-11-28     0
18  16502  2018-12-28     0
19  16502  2019-01-28     0
```